# Widgets of type PopoverMenu need placeholders to add children

Tags: gtk, glade

I'm trying to make an app in Glade and Builder using Vala, and I've gotten stuck while making the menu. Basically, what I want is the button in the titlebar with three lines, and when you click it, it shows a menu. I know how to do this with a regular Popover, but I want to use `GtkPopoveMenu` because it fits better with all of the other apps.

So I double-clicked on the grey Glade logo in the background, and clicked `GtkPopoverMenu`. Then, when I double-clicked on that and tried to add a `GtkBox`, I got a dialog saying 'Widgets of type Popover Menu need placeholders to add children.'

When I look in the XML file, there is an empty `<placeholder/>` tag.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on, or how to add these widgets?